# Can I stream a Windows App from a Linux server?

Tags: linux, windows, saas

We are transitioning from distributed software (on a disc) to software as a service (SaaS) and are looking into how to present our application to users. My question is whether it is possible to stream a Windows-based app from a Linux server via something like remote desktop or terminal services?

Note: The user is not getting a whole desktop though, just an icon which would remotely launch the application. Similar to Citrix XenApp.

Comment: Only if the app can be recompiled for Linux or if the app is .NET and fully compatible with Mono. Windows is really far behind on this stuff.

Comment: Best bet may be "Terminal Services" or similar, which unfortunately serves up the entire desktop, not just the app you need.

Comment: I'd take a look at [Xrdp](http://www.xrdp.org) and [Wine](http://www.winehq.org). Those two could do what you need. Really depends on what app you have ...

Answer (score 0):

As @Tim already mentioned, the only way this is possible is if your app can be recompiled for Linux and/or it is Java and/or it is .NET and compatible with Mono.

If that isn't the case (fairly likely in my experience) you'll need to go with something like XenApp, which requires a Windows Server host, but can deliver to just about every platform as a consumer.